# upgrading iPhone app to universal and now using splitview

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, ios-universal-app

I have an iPhone app that works and is getting used.  I now want to upgrade this application to a Universal app.  Taking that into consideration I've already made changes, like creating another `MainWindow.xib` for the iPad, which i've gotten to work.  I've pretty much got the whole iPhone App working for the iPad.  The next step I needed to take was to convert my Events Calendar to be a splitview.  As far as I can tell, I'm don't need to change any of the logic in the two controllers I already have (`CalendarViewController` and `CalendarDetailViewController`).

That being said, what is the best way to make them work on a splitview?  Is it possible to have the splitview use these two controllers (since a splitview has two controllers by default, a `TableViewController` and a `ViewController`)? Would I then need to create another `appDelegate` or something to pass all the right information back to the `MainWindow.xib`?  Or am I going to need to create a new `SplitViewController`? and if so, how would I then combine all the logic from my two Calendar Controllers?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using StoryBoard: drag a `SplitViewController` into the iPad StoryBoard.  Also be sure your two desired `UIViewControllers` are in there.  Control-click on the `SplitViewController` and drag over to each `UIViewController` and select you how want it set.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using StoryBoards...perhaps I may need to rewrite my app to use them...

Comment: I would highly recommend switching to StoryBoards as they are much easier to use and much more functional.  This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208499/how-to-convert-a-nib-based-project-to-a-storyboard-based

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look into and most likely end up adopting it and moving forward with my app.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late to answer this question but if someone needs... 
You don´t need another appDelegate, you just need to check (in appDelegate) whether your device is an iPad, and then set an array of view Controllers with the MasterVC and the DetailVC. Otherwise you will set your rootViewController as you are doing now in the iPhone app.

It would be something similar to that:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[...]

YourMasterVC *mvc =
[[YourMasterVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

UINavigationController *masterNav =
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mvc];

YourDetailVC *dvc = [[YourDetailVC alloc] init];
cvc.detailViewController = dvc;

if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    // On iPad
    UINavigationController *detailNav =
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dvc];

    UISplitViewController *svc = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];

    svc.delegate = wvc;

    svc.viewControllers = @[masterNav, detailNav];

    self.window.rootViewController = svc;
} else {
    // On iPhone
    self.window.rootViewController = masterNav;
}

[...]

}
```